# Elasticsearch Multi match and exact matches

Tags: elasticsearch

My knowledge of Elasticsearch is a bit limited, so what I want to do might not even be possible.
Say I have an ecommerce where I want to be able to freely search on the article names and other fields, but I also want to search on exact article codes aswell. Is this possible in the same query?

Example:

```
  "articlecode": "v400",
  "name": "Earplugs for humans"
}
{
  "articlecode": "b6655",
  "name": "Hammer 400"
}
```

So can a query be written that combines both multimatch and terms? So that If I search for '400' I get 2 results, but if I search for v400 I just get one result as it is an exact match on the "articlecode"-field.

Below is our current query, where i have an ngram on the "name" field and where I use the term-keyword on the language-field.

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "v400",
          "fields": [
            "articlecode^10",
            "name^7"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "IdLang.keyword": "sv"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought of using [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-wildcard) instead of `multi_match`? Then you can use wildcard in your search:

```json
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*v400",
          "fields": [
            "articlecode^10",
            "name^7"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to search with `400` anywhere in the 2 fields, you can do `*400*`, or only leading or trailing, depending on what you want.